# Interpret term as type in Coq

Tags: coq

I am building Integers from Naturals bottom-up and trying to apply a morphism rewrite directly instead of adding it as a setoid morphism because in my case it is hard and unnatural to do it, but a test case is failing with the following error:

```
The term "x = x" has type "Prop" while it is expected to have type "x = x".
```

Which is also thrown by the following MRE:

```
Require Import Setoid.

(* Custom natural Set *)
Parameter CNat : Set.

(* Addition *) 
Parameter CAdd : CNat -> CNat -> CNat. 
Infix "±" := CAdd (at level 50, left associativity).

(* Addition Morphism *)
Axiom cnat_add_morphism : 
  forall (x x' : CNat), x = x' ->
  forall (y y' : CNat), y = y' -> 
    x ± y = x' ± y'.

(* Test Example *)
Example cnat_add_inc : 
  forall (x y c : CNat), x = y -> x±c = y±c.
Proof.
  intros x y c CH.
  rewrite (@cnat_add_morphism x x (x=x) c c (c=c)). (* #Error *)
```

Is it possible to tell `cnat_add_morphism` (which in my code is a theorem instead of an axiom) to interpret the terms `x¦x` and `c¦c` as a type to make the morphism work properly, or a different one to be able to apply a manual morphism rewrite instead of adding it as a setoid?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems here.

**First of all**, the error means you are trying to give `cnat_add_morphism` a proposition instead of a proof of that proposition. In Coq, proofs are objects of type of the proposition they are the proof of. for example, `forall x : CNat, x¦x` is a type and you have to build an object of that type to guarantee that the type is true. This is like you have a function `f : nat -> nat` and you write `f nat`, you get the following error:

```
The term "nat" has type "Set" while it is expected to have type "nat".
```

The error you are receiving is exactly the same. So you need to provide an object of type "x ¦ x" i.e., a proof that guarantees the proposition `x ¦ x` is true. So you can use the `ceq_reflexivity` axiom. The term `(ceq_reflexivity x)` has the type `x¦x` and you can use it instead of wrong usage of `x¦x`.

```
(cnat_add_morphism x x (ceq_reflexivity x))
```

**Second**, you need to apply the lemma not rewrite it and use the assumption instead of `x¦x` (use x and y not x only).

```
apply (cnat_add_morphism x y CH c c (ceq_reflexivity c)).
```

Answer (score 1):

The first problem you have is that the term you want to rewrite is not well-typed:

```
cnat_add_morphism x x (x¦x) c c (c¦c)
```

You have

```
cnat_add_morphism x x : x¦x -> forall y y', y¦y' -> x ± y ¦ x ± y'
```

so you need to provide a proof of `x¦x` but you're providing `x¦x` itself.
You actually need to add proofs of reflexivity in your system. Something like

```
Parameter CRefl : forall (x : CNat), x¦x.
```

Then you can prove your lemma.

```
Example cnat_add_inc : 
  forall (x y c : CNat), 
    x¦y -> 
    x ± c ¦ y ± c.
Proof.
  intros x y c CH.
  apply cnat_add_morphism.
  - assumption.
  - apply CRefl.
Qed.
```

Comment: I dont want to `apply cnat_add_morphism`, I want to apply `rewrite cnat_add_morphism` to the left side, which can be done implicitly if I added `cnat_add_morphism` as a setoid morphism (https://coq.inria.fr/refman/addendum/generalized-rewriting.html).

Comment: Yes I know, but that was not the problem with your definition, you wanted to rewrite something ill-typed. Also now you have edited your post to use equality, so then `rewrite` would work. If you want to keep your own notion of equality then you need to use setoid rewrite.

Comment: Right I have to provide a proof, did not understand that point. Not bad answer